# Running Excel on Ubuntu: Solver & Macro crashes

Tags: libreoffice, playonlinux

first of all I would like to say that I am a total noob at linux / ubuntu. 
I have just migrated from Windows 7 and so far I feel quite satisfied with the change.
I've tried using LibreOffice but VBA Macros there don't run quite well. So I downloaded PlayOnLinux and installed Office 2010, but when I try to run a Macro or use the Solver Add-In, Excel crashes. 
Is there a way this problem could be fixed? Or how do i make LibreOffice to run my macro without errors?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Libre Office online help mentions the incompatibility with MS Office macros. ([Using Microsoft Office and LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Using_Microsoft_Office_and)):

> With a few exceptions, Microsoft Office and LibreOffice cannot run the
>   same macro code.

Nevertheless, they suggest some macros may still work:

> The most recent versions of LibreOffice can run some Excel Visual
>   Basic scripts if you enable this feature at LibreOffice -
>   PreferencesTools - Options - Load/Save - VBA Properties.

However, I suspect your macros are pretty complex.  This is one of the issues converting to Linux 100%-- the rest of the world still uses the MS Office suite, it does its job well, but is not fully open standards compliant.  I hate to suggest this, but have you considered installing Windows as a virtual machine (such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) inside Ubuntu just to use Excel?  VirtualBox is available in the Ubuntu Software Center, and you will need a licensed Windows CD and MS Office CD to install them in Virtual Box.